# Poisson sand timer

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Imagine a sand clock that drops grains of sand from an upper bulb to the lower one at random intervals.

The probability that $k$ grains of sand are dropped in $t$ seconds is

$$\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}$$

Assume $\lambda$ is known. How can I estimate the elapsed time when I see $n$ more grains of sand in the lower bulb?

I guess the problem is very common. What is the canonical approach? Should I compute the a confidence interval for $t$? How? Or, what else?

Comment: $\lambda$ is the rate at which grains drop in a Poisson process, so your expected time for $n$ more grains would be $\frac{n}{\lambda}$.  If the Poisson model is correct, the actual time would have a Gamma or Erlang distribution

Answer (score 1):

Note that  ${{\left( {\lambda t} \right)^{\,k} } \over {k!}}e^{\, - \,\lambda \,t} $
can actually be written as
$$
P(k|t) = {{\left( {\lambda t} \right)^{\,k} } \over {k!}}e^{\, - \,\lambda \,t} 
$$
being the probability of having $k$ grains in a given interval $t$.

$\lambda=1/t_0$ is just a scale factor for $t$, so can take $\tau= \lambda t = t/t_0$ to be a time interval
measured in that scale. So
$$
P(k|\tau ) = {{\tau ^{\,k} } \over {k!}}e^{\, - \,\,\tau } 
$$

Suppose $\tau$ to have a uniform a-priori distribution over a (large) interval $T$, then
$$
P(k \cap \tau ) = {\tau  \over T}{{\tau ^{\,k} } \over {k!}}e^{\, - \,\,\tau } 
$$
and
$$
P(\tau |n) = {{P(n \cap \tau )} \over {P(n)}} = P(\tau  \cap n) = {\tau  \over T}{{\tau ^{\,n} } \over {n!}}e^{\, - \,\,\tau } 
$$
will be the probability that, given $n$ grains,  the period of time extends till $\tau$ (i.e. the CDF).

Similarly, if the a-priori probability for $\tau$ be a different function.

Comment: Thank you.  The answer is perfect when a natural choice of the a-priori probability.